# Train HMM using MALLET

Tags: mallet, hmmlearn

I am very new in using MALLET. I need to have a library of HMM for sequence labelling task. I already look at  [Sequence Tagging Developer's Guide](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/fst.php), but i am unable to understand that how can I train HMM. I have a list of Hidden States, a list of observation symbols, initial probability matrix, transition probability matrix and emission probability matrix. I need to train HMM by using B-W algorithm, to re-estimate the parameters and then want to perform sequence labelling task using those parameters.

As example, I have the following values:

**hidden_states** = ('Rainy', 'Sunny')

**observation_symbols** = ('walk', 'shop', 'clean')

**initial_probability** = {'Rainy': 0.6, 'Sunny': 0.4}

**transition_probability** = {

'Rainy' : {'Rainy': 0.7, 'Sunny': 0.3},

'Sunny' : {'Rainy': 0.4, 'Sunny': 0.6},

}

**emission_probability** = {

'Rainy' : {'walk': 0.1, 'shop': 0.4, 'clean': 0.5},

'Sunny' : {'walk': 0.6, 'shop': 0.3, 'clean': 0.1},

}

**observation_sequence** = {

walk clean shop,

clean walk shop

}

How can I train HMM using the above parameters? Please help.

Comment: Baum-Welch estimates the initial, transition, and emission probabilities from data. It doesn't look like you have enough observation sequences to do a good job of that. You may need to generate more data.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that the intention of this problem is to trace the steps of Baum-Welch "manually" in order to better understand the algorithm.

Comment: I have enough data to train the model, here I am showing a very small example. I have around 20 number of hidden states, 100 number of observation symbols, 700 number of observation sequences and also have all probability values (initial). I want to re-estimate the parameters using B-W algorithm and then want to use those for tagging. But i can't understand how can i give those inputs , how can i set those values to train the model, which classes and variables of MALLET are exactly use to do this. I am unable to understand the format of training data file. Please help.

Comment: I have found the classes of MALLET, used to build and train the HMM :-  
`cc.mallet.fst.HMM`,   
`cc.mallet.fst.HMMTrainerByLikelihood`  .   But i am unable to understand how can I set parameters and use the classes to train and test the model. Please help.